# Minecraft won't launch on limited internet connection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Currently I don't have a proper Internet connection in my flat, so I'm using a free wifi network offered by my city. It's fine for browsing the web, sending emails etc., but things like downloads are heavily restricted. This is causing problems for me with Minecraft.

If I try to run Minecraft from the launcher while connected to this free network, it seems that Minecraft decides to try to download updates, but can't, because the network doesn't allow it. This results in me being unable to run the game, as even if I try again when I'm not connected, Minecraft seems to still have the information that it "needs" the new update.

All I want to do is play offline, usually I just disconnect and then launch Minecraft, but today I forgot to disconnect, so now it looks like I'm going to have to find a proper network so it can do the updates and try to remember to disconnect in future. This is tedious, so I was wondering - is there a way to get Minecraft to "forget" about the new updates, and then just disconnect and try running the game again? If anyone has any suggestions I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your profile so that Minecraft doesn't try to download updates. On the launcher click "Edit Profile" in the bottom left. Look for "Minecraft Version". You should have "use latest version" selected. Click the dropdown arrow and select a recent version of minecraft (for example 1.8) to play. The launcher will then play the already downloaded version every time, and won't try to update the game.